# List of class properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have ASP.NET MVC 4 application with one view model class and about 20 views representing this view model. This views differs only by fields which user can edit. I want to merge all that views to one and define list of properties available to editing in strongly-typed manner. Ideally, I want something like this:

```
// Action
public ActionResult EditAsEngineer(int id)
{
    //...
    viewModel.PropertiesToChange = new List<???>()
    {
        v => v.LotNumber,
        v => v.ShippingDate,
        v => v.Commentary
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}

// View
if (@Model.PropertiesToChange.Contains(v => v.LotNumber)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LotNumber)
}
else
{
    @Model.LotNumber
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Or is there a better solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why note something like this (**its pseudo code**)

```
public class Prop{
   string PropertyName {get;set;}
   bool PropertyEditable {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult EditAsEngineer(int id)
{
    viewModel.PropertiesToChange = new List<Prop>()
    {
        new Prop{PropertyName = LotNumber, PropertyEditable  = true}
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}

@foreach (var pin Model.PropertiesToChange)
{
   if(p.PropertyEditable){
      @Html.TextBoxFor(p)
   }else{
      @Html.DisplayFor(p)
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use magic strings, because it can lead to silent bugs and kill auto-refactoring

Comment: Where do you see magicstrings ? Replace the string PropertyName by your object. As I said its pseudo code :)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve HALF of your problem. You will also need to create a `IEqualityComparer<Expression>` for your code to work (the default is to check for ref-equals).

```
    return from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
            let param = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x")
            let propExp = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(param, p)
            let cast = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(propExp, typeof(object))
            let displayAttribute = p.CustomAttributes.OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute>()
                        .Select(x => x.Order).DefaultIfEmpty(int.MaxValue).FirstOrDefault()
            orderby displayAttribute
            select System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(cast, new [] {param});
```

This will list out ALL the properties for T. You would also probabily want to use `Expression<Func<T, object>>` as the type for defining your list of properties.

This will allow you to create a generic view over all properties.

Also you will want to wrap this in some kind of a cache, as this code is SLOW.